# subdomain relative linking

Tags: html, hyperlink, subdomain

I've my site running fine on localhost.

```
localhost/project/entitlement

<form action="signIn">
username + password input fields
</form> 

(works fine and resolves to following on form submission)

http://localhost/project/entitlement/signIn
```

but when I upload on my host it stops working.

URL of my host:

```
subdomain.elasticbeanstalk.com/entitlement
```

How can I make the relative link work for both cases for the Form tag.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: edited, please let me know if still not clear.